# Subviews appearing in unexpected order when height constraint changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a "hidden" UIView that contains two UIViews within a UITableViewCell.

1. A button
2. A separator line at the top (a UIView with a background color)

For testing, I've also applied a background color to the hidden view itself.

There is a default constraint that sets height = 0 with a priority of 999 on the view.

When I set the constraint priority to 1, the view appears (as expected), but the button appears immediately while the separator line and the background color of the containing view appear only once the animation is completed.

I am forcing the animation by calling:

```
[table beginUpdates];
[table endUpdates];
```

And the cell expands appropriately.  I'm guessing it has something to do with backgrounds being drawn last, but I haven't been able to figure out how to affect the ordering.

Comment: Hello Justin, have you set the priorities of both the button and separator line as well?

Comment: The constraint priorities are equivalent for both.  Is there some sort of rendering I can apply?  I do have a solution whereby I might unhide the view as soon as the animation is completed.

Comment: Hmm... I could not say for sure without some code to look at. I do, however, know a good tutorial that you may skip through just to make sure you have added everything: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWgr_wNtGPM&app=desktop